# Repeating a test, one iteration for each web browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to be able to execute a given test multiple times, one iteration for each browser type.

Easier said than done. I have no idea how I would do this. Has anyone ever tried to code such a thing? If so would you be willing to share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Create separate classes for each browser type which you wish to add.(You can add FirefoxDriver,ChromeDriver,SafariDriver,IEDriver and etc)Because browsers has different ways of configurations.Then create the Main class which will hold method for your *test*.That method takes only one parameter of  WebDriver type .Then Import those browser classes to the main class and create WebDriver objects from each of them.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

After that put them into a array type of WebDriver objects.After that Using a for loop call that method by passing each and every object from the array.

Example:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            test(array[i]);

        }
```

Hope this helps